# Installing xdebug on Ubuntu LAMP stack

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, xdebug

I keep throwing this error but I have version 7.1.2 installed. Why can't I `./configure`

Here is my error message:

```
checking whether to enable Xdebug support... yes, shared
checking Check for supported PHP versions... configure: error: not supported. 
Need a PHP version >= 7.0.0 and < 7.3.0 (found 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26)
    root@precise32:/var/www/xdebug# php -v
    PHP 7.1.2-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2017 10:29:40) ( NTS )
    Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
        with Zend OPcache v7.1.2-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    root@precise32:/var/www/xdebug#
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem. I've tried reinstalling php 7.0 and several other tactics. Read through a bunch of different stack questions similar but I can't figure it out.

Which means I can't move on to: `make`

```
make install

cp modules/xdebug.so /etc/php.d/xdebug.so
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the PPA from Ondřej Surý. So you can easily install xdebug by using `apt-get install php7.1-xdebug`.

**Edit:** How-To configure Xdebug (on Ubuntu based Linux systems):

Create an ini file `/etc/php/7.1/mods-available/custom.ini` and put the following configuration into it:

```
; priority=90
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
; replace <Host-IP-Address> with the IP of your host system!
xdebug.remote_host=<Host-IP-Address>
; You'll need this later.
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
```

Now activate the configuration with the command `sudo phpenmod -v 7.1 -s ALL custom`. Don't forget to restart your web server.

Second you need an IDE which supports the `dbgp` protocol. I use PhpStorm, it's fast (even it runs for hours) and of cause, it has a native Xdebug support.

After you've set up your IDE and set at least one breakpoint in your code, you can trigger the debugger very simple:

1st option: Add the query parameter `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM` (where `PHPSTORM` is the value of the `xdebug.idekey` setting in your configuration file).

2nd option: Send a cookie with the content `XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM` with your request. cURL example: `curl -H 'Cookie: XDEBUBG_SESSION=PHPSTORM' http://my-awesome.domain/awesome-script.php`.

If you've set up anything correctly, you can now play with Xdebug.

Xdebug - [Documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/)
PhpStorm - [Configuring Xdebug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/configuring-xdebug.html)
PhpStorm - [Zero-configuration Web Application Debugging with Xdebug and PhpStorm](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm)

And last but not least, some nice-to-have Xdebug settings:

```
; enable colors for the command-line interface
xdebug.cli_color=1

; show more data when using var_dump
xdebug.max_nesting_level=500
xdebug.var_display_max_children=512
xdebug.var_display_max_data=2560
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=200

; enable trigger for easy profiling
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
```

Have nice debugging sessions :)

Comment: Thank you. It looks like that installed and was super easy. Now if i do a php-v. php -v
PHP 7.1.2-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1 
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans

Comment: This may be a stupid question and I'm certainly going to check your answer as the correct one because it got xdebug installed for me. But, how do you actually use debug? Where are the tools how do i know it's working etc etc?

Comment: I edited my post and added a small How-To configure Xdebug.

Comment: Do I have to use PHPSTORM?

Comment: No. You can use what ever you want, as long as it doesn't contain special characters or whitespaces. Another example: `xdebug.idekey=MyAwesomeProject` --> `http://my-awesome.domain/awesome-script.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=MyAwesomeProject`

Comment: Got it, I'm currently using ATOM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137091/discussion-between-supplement-and-kyoya).